# Print producing wrong output in java

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I was practicing linked list in Java. So, I made three nodes and gave them value 1,2 and 3. When I run the code I want the output

```
1 2 3
```

But the code is giving output

```
333435
```

I checked the code,and it seems correct. I don't know why code is producing unexpected output. Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
class LinkedList{
    Node head;

    static class Node
    {
            int data;
            Node next;
            Node(int d){
                data = d;
                next = null;
           }
    }
    public void printList(){
        Node n = head;
        while (n != null){
            System.out.print(n.data + ' ');
            n = n.next;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();

        llist.head  = new Node(1);
        Node second= new Node(2);
        Node third = new Node(3);

        llist.head.next = second;
        second.next = third;

        llist.printList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do System.out.print(n.data + " "); instead of System.out.print(n.data + ' ');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct , but the problem you are facing lies within

```
System.out.print(n.data + ' ');
```

instead do

`System.out.print(n.data + " ");`

First you should know :-

single quotes are used for characters and double quotes are used for strings.

When you do

```
 n.data + ' '
```

It converts ' ' to its ASCII value and adds it to n.data.
ASCII character of space is 32.So, your output becomes

1 +32 ==33

2 + 32 = 34

2 + 33 = 35

Hence,

333435

and there will be no space, because space is converted into ASCII value
Similar type codes will produce same outputs.

Eg:-

System.out.print(n.data + '*');

Comment: Thanks for making my day. I learned a whole new thing from your post.

Answer (score 1):

In your printList() method, you have:

```
// this converts the space char to an int and adds it the data.
System.out.print(n.data + ' ');
```

Change it to:

```
// this will print the data and concatenate a space after it
System.out.print(n.data + " ");
```

**Note**: The space char in ascii is 32 in decimal and this is why you were getting 33, 34, and 35